# Snapcraft error whith glib-compile-schemas

Tags: gnome, snap

I'm trying to build a snap for gnome-commander. Constantly failing is glib-compile-schemas:

```
+ glib-compile-schemas /snap/snapcraft/5756/share/glib-2/schemas
Error opening directory “/snap/snapcraft/5756/share/glib-2/schemas”: No such file or directory
```

This is from my snapcraft.yaml:

```
  desktop-settings-build:
    plugin: nil
    after: [ gcmd, desktop-gnome-platform ]
    override-prime: |
       set -eux
       glib-compile-schemas $SNAP/share/glib-2/schemas
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Best regards

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it: Surely it is glib-2.0, not glib2. Damned typos! :-)